# How do you make UIWebView Look exactly like mobile safari when a page loads? (not super zommed in)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, mobile-safari

how do i make my uiwebview look exactly like safari when a page loaded , take for example this page 
http://www.240-voltz.com/

it does not load like safari where i can choose where to zoom in?

cant upload images need 10 reps !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

managed to configure it to set to

> Scale pages to fit

in interface builder!